# Proving ring with given conditions

Tags: ring-theory

$($$R$$,$$+$$,$$.$$)$ satisfies all axioms of ring except commutative property of addition.If right cancellation law holds in $($$R$$,$$+$$,$$.$$)$.Prove that it is a ring.please help.

Answer (score 0):

Of course $a+b=b+a$ for $b=0$. Let $a,b\in R$, with $b\ne0$. Then
$$
(a+b)(b+b)=a(b+b)+b(b+b)=ab+ab+b^2+b^2
$$
On the other hand
$$
(a+b)(b+b)=(a+b)b+(a+b)b=ab+b^2+ab+b^2
$$
Since cancellation holds for $+$, you can conclude that…

> $$ab+b^2=b^2+ab$$ which can be rewritten$$(a+b)b=(b+a)b$$